# Data Model Architecture - More Fields or New Object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, data, architecture, data-model

I am reassessing an existing data model in use in my org and looking to ensure it's following best practices.

The custom object is called a ticket. If the ticket record meets certain criteria, it is then sent to another salesforce org where it is then created as a case to be worked.

In the existing process, another object called Ticket Transfer Log is created to log whether or not the request to send the log to the other log was successful or not, response time, case number in other org, etc. In the case of a failure, a batch job picks up the failed requests and attempts to resend.

In my analysis, I think the data model becomes more complicated by adding the log object with the lookup relationship back to the custom object. One more object to maintain. I would think it would make more sense to move the necessary fields to the Ticket Object, although they would only be used for a subset of record (~10% of records meet the criteria).

I believe this may come down to use case, but I would think there must be some general guidelines to follow.

What are the salesforce recommended approach to making these types of data model decisions.

If this is something that is too opinionated and cannot be answer definitively, please let me know I will revoke the question.

Comment: It's not really Salesforce specific, it's just that with the `Ticket Transfer Log` object you can support more flexibility, such as a) multiple attempts recorded as separate logs b) pushes to multiple target orgs.

You need to weigh your use case against a YAGNI principle. If you never care about more than the latest attempt's log and you never push to more than one org you can just add fields to your `Ticket__c`. Otherwise, keep the `Log`.

Comment: @Zaitman, appreciate the thoughts. I'll look into the YAGNI principle, considerations I was particularly looking for were things like data skew, general maintainability, reusability. I could add a field to track the # of attempts if I wanted to do as well, or I could have generic object used for all items that send to various endpoints if I wanted a more generic approach to retries.